# Wordpress “Categories to tags converter” not working. Pointing to import.php instead

Tags: plugins, categories, tags

I just imported my posts from blogger into wordpress. In doing this, the tags were converted to categories for some strange reason.

I am now trying to convert them back into tag using wordpress' built in converter. However, whenever I click on the "Category to tag converter" link, it directs me to the import page "/import.php". Is there anything i can do to rectify this.

Alternatively, could someone please copy the end of the URL for the converter tool's page, and paste it here so i can append it to my blog URL. Im guessing that could work meanwhile.

Cheers in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually included with WordPress, you'll need to download it.

Plugin can be found here.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpcat2tag-importer/

Once that's activated you'll be able to reach the importer at.
**yoursite.com/wp-admin/import.php?import=wpcat2tag**

Hope that helps.